# Where can I pre-trained data files for Tesseract OCR for english language fax documents?

Tags: tesseract

I am using tesseract from java through tess4j. Is there a well known traineddata file for english language for fax documents in the US? It will be of great help to get pre-trained files for medical fax documents (pahology reports, authorization decoments, referral letters, etc.)

I am already using the out-of-the-box traineddata files, but I am looking for something which works on faxed documents.

I have also tried training on my own dataset but my data set is very small and not representative of what I will encounter in the real world.